# How can i make a div overlap the surrounding divs, when the user hovers over it?

Tags: html, css

I'm am facing this problem. I'd like to have a field of divs align next to each other. When the user hovers over the div, the div changes its background-color and gets bigger. With that, it should also be over the divs next to it. But it doesn't do that on one side.

I tried it with different aproaches, like setting the `z-index` from *.thin* to 1000 and the one from `.thin:hover` to 1200 and also tried to change the position to absolute, which made it be over the other ones but floating on the left side.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    z-index: -1;
    position:relative;
}
.tiles{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-content: center;
}
.thin {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #EFF0F1;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: table;
}

    .thin:hover {
        width: 190px;
        height: 190px;
        background-color: #01A3EE;
        margin: -13px;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear, margin 600ms linear, width 600ms linear, height 600ms linear;
        -ms-transition: background-color 300ms linear, margin 600ms linear, width 600ms linear, height 600ms linear;
        transition: background-color 300ms linear, margin 600ms linear, width 600ms linear, height 600ms linear;
    }
    
    p {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_parent">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
    <meta>
    <meta>
</head>
<body onfocusout="" style="" onload="">
    <div id="" class="tiles">
        <div id="" class="thin">
            <p id="">Residential Property</p>
        </div>
        <div id="" class="thin">
            <p id="">Sales Lead</p>
        </div>
        <div id="" class="thin">
            <p id="">Sales Opportunity</p>
        </div>
        <div id="" class="thin">
            <p id="">Purchase Lead</p>
        </div>
        <div id="" class="thin">
            <p id="">Purchase Opportunity</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So how can i make the div overlap the surrounding divs without moving the div to a different location.

I hope, someone can help with my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is working example: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thezeeshantariq/oucws5kb/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    some text
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    some text
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    some text
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements - below I have made your box relative and added a higher `z-index` to the hover

The only way to make the elements not move when hovered is to use a transform and scale them, instead of changing their physical width and height.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tiles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-content: center;
}

.thin {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #EFF0F1;
  margin: 3px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: table;             
                                     /* added below 2 lines */
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.thin:hover {
  background-color: #01A3EE;
  transform: scale(1.2);              /* change the width and height to a scale transformation so element doesn't move on resize, also no need to repeat items declared in .thin, unless you need to override them */
  
  z-index: 2;                         /* add this */
  -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear, transform 600ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 300ms linear, transform 600ms linear;
  transition: background-color 300ms linear, transform 600ms linear;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_parent">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title></title>
  <meta>
  <meta>
</head>

<body onfocusout="" style="" onload="">
  <div id="" class="tiles">
    <div id="" class="thin">
      <p id="">Residential Property</p>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="thin">
      <p id="">Sales Lead</p>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="thin">
      <p id="">Sales Opportunity</p>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="thin">
      <p id="">Purchase Lead</p>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="thin">
      <p id="">Purchase Opportunity</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: "So how can i make the div overlap the surrounding divs without moving the div to a different location." This is still the case in your snippet

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `scale(1.1);` grow the `div`, it is the much simpler way to do the needful. You only need to update the CSS of `:hover`

```
    .thin:hover {
       transform: scale(1.1);
       background-color: #01A3EE;
       float: left;
       border-radius: 3px;
       transition: all 0.3s linear;
     }
```